# Is there a way to skip YouTube ads by a click or button without waiting 5 seconds or more

Tags: youtube

It is frustrating having to wait 5 seconds each time or 10 seconds to see a repetitive or unwanted ad also you don't want to block ads using a blocker.
is there an addon to do that with just one click.

Comment: No way you have to wait for some second

Comment: Yes, if you can't live with ad blockers, you will have to live with ads...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, The only way is to subscribe for YouTube premium service than YouTube will not serve ad on the videos you watch.

Answer (score 0):

If you're keen on using the respective first-party website or app provided by Google, then your best option is indeed to get [YouTube Premium](https://www.youtube.com/premium), as described by AmitDigitech.

---

It's unclear why using an ad blocker is an unsatisfactory solution. If the motivation is that you want to continue supporting creators, then the rest of this post will be irrelevant for you, but may help others.

There is an alternative solution if one just can't use an ad blocker for technical reasons, for example:

- The ad blocker was breaking other functionality.
- Can't install extensions due to using an organization managed device.
- The device or client doesn't support blocking ads, i.e. some mobile browsers.

One can use a third-party YouTube client. Most if not all third-party clients don't feature ads in the first-place. A few options are listed below.

#### Browser

[Invidious](https://invidious.io/) is a free and open-source client/server to access content from YouTube.

A popular instance is: https://yewtu.be/
There's also an API displaying a list of public instances: https://api.invidious.io/

[image]

#### Android (Mobile/TV)

[NewPipe](https://newpipe.net/) which is an app available on [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.schabi.newpipe/) and installable with the [APK](https://github.com/TeamNewPipe/NewPipe/releases).

[image]

#### Kodi

There is [plugin.video.invidious](https://github.com/lekma/plugin.video.invidious) for Kodi, which lets you browse and watch content on YouTube through Invidious. This requires installing a third-party repository, as it's not available in the official ones.

[image]

#### Desktop

You can use [FreeTube](https://freetubeapp.io/) which is an app available to install on Linux, Windows, and macOS.

[image]

###### Linux (Flatpak)

```
flatpak install flathub io.freetubeapp.FreeTube
```

###### Windows

```
winget install -e --id PrestonN.FreeTube
```